# Checking if application is already running

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Java Application that uses JPA on a file DB.

I want only one instance of my application running (Note that the DB gets locked to the first instance of the application).

How could I check if my DB is locked or not, and present a message to the user?

Comment: you can create a .lock file when your application starts getting hooked to DB, and delete that .lock file after the app stops..  if one more instance of app runs and if it sees .lock file already present, then show the message.

Comment: If you start a second instance does it throw a SQLException indicating that the database is locked? If it does, would it be sufficient to just catch that exception and display a more meaningful exception back to the user?

Comment: @sanbhat, I've been looking to that option, but I hear it's not fully.

Comment: @DaveHowes, It does do that, but I hoped there would be a better way to handle that, I can do it that way though.

Comment: Each of the quick-win approaches ( either trap the SQLException or use a .lock file ) has drawbacks which may leave you with a false positive - effectively locking you out of the application. I think the SQLException is the better option as it is a more natural fit to your problem. ( The database tells you when more than one person is accessing it, rather than relying on the existence of a file ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet your DB with its ip and the port number.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse solve this solution with a .lock file. Other solution can be: try to use a port: bind to port 12345. If you can than you are the only one king of the hill if you can't, than maybe other are using that hill. Any other apps can.

The .lock file has many disadvantages too.

And the last and best solution is: do it with platform dependent at way at OS level via JNI, but require a lot of work and has disadvantages too.